# div tag inside the td tag results an addition of a new line while copying the table content to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to copy my HTML table elements to the clipboard. But I have used div tag inside the td tag of the table. I think that what adding a new line after pasting the contents from clipboard. I want that to stay in the same line. Please help how to make it possible.

**Sample Output**

ProfileUID :    12345
First Name :    John
Email : John.doe@xyz.com
Profile Status :    Enabled
Country Code :  United States (+1)
**Phone No.** :
+1- 456789125

Last Generated OTP :    x5xx555
Employee ID :   223344
User ID :   johndoe

**Required Output**

ProfileUID :    12345
First Name :    John
Email : John.doe@xyz.com
Profile Status :    Enabled
Country Code :  United States (+1)
**Phone No.** :  +1- 456789125
Last Generated OTP :    x5xx555
Employee ID :   223344
User ID :   johndoe

*Have a look at the **Phone No.** texts in both the above outputs.*

**index.html**

```
<div style="margin-left: 2rem">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="background-color: #001872; display: none" onclick="copyTable(document.getElementById('table'))" id="copy"> <i class="fa-regular fa-copy"></i> </button>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover" style="display: none" id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr align="center">
            <th style="width: 20%" class="col-sm-4 text-center" scope="row">ProfileUID :</th>
            <td style="width: 50%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <th style="width: 20%" class="col-sm-4 text-center" scope="row">First Name :</th>
            <td style="width: 50%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <th style="width: 20%" class="col-sm-4 text-center" scope="row">Email :</th>
            <td style="width: 50%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <th style="width: 20%" class="col-sm-4 text-center" scope="row">Profile Status :</th>
            <td style="width: 50%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <th style="width: 20%" class="col-sm-4 text-center" scope="row">Country Code :</th>
            <td style="width: 50%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 20%" class="col-sm-4 text-center" scope="row" style="padding-top: 12px;"> Phone No. :</th>
            <form action="" method="post" id="form2" style="display: inline-block;"> {% csrf_token %}
                <td style="width: 50%">
                    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
                        <div style="width: 25%;" id="1"></div>
                        <div style="width:100%; border: 0px solid red; align-self: center; text-align: center;" id="2"></div>
                        <div style="border: 0px solid blue; width: 25%; text-align: right">
                            <button type="button" id="edit" style="border-style: none; background-color:transparent; color:#001872;" onclick="edits()"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-pen fa-2x"></i> </button>
                            <button type="submit" id="save" style="display:none; border-style: none; background-color:transparent; color:#17d647e8; padding: 2px;" onclick="saved()"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-check fa-2x"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" id="cancel" style="display:none; border-style: none; background-color:transparent; color:#c42c2c;"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-xmark fa-2x" onclick="canceled()"></i></button>
                        </div>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <th style="width: 20%" class="col-sm-4 text-center" scope="row"> Last Generated OTP : </th>
            <td style="width: 50%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <th style="width: 20%" class="col-sm-4 text-center" scope="row">Employee ID :</th>
            <td style="width: 50%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <th style="width: 20%" class="col-sm-4 text-center" scope="row">User ID :</th>
            <td style="width: 50%"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**script.js**

```
function copyTable(el) {
  var body = document.body,
    range,
    sel;
  if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
    range = document.createRange();
    sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    try {
      range.selectNodeContents(el);
      sel.addRange(range);
    } catch (e) {
      range.selectNode(el);
      sel.addRange(range);
    }
  } else if (body.createTextRange) {
    range = body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(el);
    range.select();
  }
  document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Div tag is Block Element.
Block Element makes a new line.
I think this css code will work.

```
div {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Hello @이연준,
This is not a CSS issue. It's happening after hitting the COPY button which has a JS logic. I am assuming by making changes in the JS code can resolves the issue. However, I have tried your answer as well and it has not resolved the issue. The issue still persists.

Comment: @akc121 I'm sorry i didn't know that. I hope you solve that issue

Comment: nope. Unfortunately, the issue still persists.